# Spinner - How to put user's selection at top position

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner, android-adapter

I was wondering if someone could help me with my code. I have a spinner containing six items in an array with the third item set as the default. When the user selects an item, I want the user's selection to move to the top position in the spinner. To clarify, if I have items A, B, C, D, E, and F:

Default:

```
C

--

A

B

D

E

F
```

If the user selects D:

```
D

--

A

B

C

E

F
```

As shown in the "diagram," I'm also trying to figure out how to put a divider only on the top selection.

Here's the code I have so far. I've just started learning Android so I'm quite iffy on everything, but any help is appreciated, thank you!

-- UPDATED CODE --

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

List<String> list;
String [] objects = {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objects));

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setSelection(2);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
    list.remove(pos);
    objects=list.toArray(new String[0]);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: I do not believe you need a listener nor adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). Spinner should automatically put the user's choice at top. onItemSelected is used whenever you want to do something when the user selects a specific item in the spinner.

Comment: Sorry, the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() was leftover code I forgot to delete when I was trying solutions to similar questions. I also plan to later use the spinner to change the information displayed on the page, which is why I included the listener - for example, clicking A will display information about A, B will display information about B, etc.

Comment: To further clarify, let's say the user selected B. Now when they click the spinner again, I want it to look like B -- A C D E F Right now, I'm getting this dropdown menu no matter what the user has selected: A B C D E F; so in other words, I want the user's selections to be at the top and no longer included in the other choices. I'm also looking to get the divider between the user's selection and the rest of the choices. Thanks for your response!

Comment: If the answer below does not help you, I think I have a solution for you problem.

Comment: As a beginner, I'm still a little confused and would love to hear your solution as well please.

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if you need any sort of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to achieve the layout you want, you have to have a custom adapter.

So you need to define a class as follows:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
   Context c;
String [] objects;
   public MyAdapter(Context c, String [] objects){
          this.c=c;
this.objects=objects;
   }


    @Override 
   public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) { 
    return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
 } 
    @Override 
     public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) { 
return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt); 
           }
        }

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 

{ 
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater(); 
View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false); 
RelativeLayout layout= (RelativeLayout) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.layout);
TextView letter= (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.letter);
 letter.setText(objects[position]);
 if(position==0){
 layout.setVisibility(true);
 }
return mySpinner;
}
```

As for the xml which is custom_spinner.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/letter"
android:height="wrap_content"
android:width="wrap_content"/>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View 
android:id="@+id/line"
android:height="1dp"
android:width="5dp"/>
<View
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/line"
    android:height="1dp"
android:width="5dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity:

```
MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(this, spinnerValues);
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As for removing the selected item from the dropdown:

You have to have the following in the activity:

```
List<String> list;
String [] objects;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerTime);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
objects= {"A","B","C","D","E","F"};
list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objects));
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        objects, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(2);

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                           int pos, long id) {
  list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.array.time_period));
  list.remove(pos);
  objects=list.toArray(new String[0]);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

Comment: I've been working with the code that you provided (thank you very much!) but I've come across one error that I've been unable to solve. For 'RelativeLayout layout= mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.layout);
            TextView letter= mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.letter);' 
I get an error saying "Incompatible types. Required: android.widget.RelativeLayout/Textview. Found: android.view.View

Comment: Also, I was just wondering (I haven't tried it yet, since I can't get the code to run :/) if there will be an issue with the selected item returning to the dropdown when another item is selected? For example, if I select C, it goes to the top and is removed from the choices. If I select D afterwards, D will go to the top and is removed from the choices, but will C return to the choices?

Comment: @Kathy yes it will return C supposedly do not worry and regarding the error I will check it and update the code immediately

Comment: @Kathy please check my updated code and get back to me :D I am ready to help

Comment: Thanks a lot for your consistent help! The old error is gone now, but I'm coming across some new errors in this bit of code:

  MyAdapter adapter= new MyAdapter(this, spinnerValues);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        List<String> list= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objects));

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
            list.remove(pos);
            objects=list.toArray(new String[0]);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

It says it cannot resolve the symbol "spinnerValues," "objects," or "list" :/

Comment: I should probably also mention that I changed a bit of the code because I was getting an error, but maybe I shouldn't have. I changed : "public MyAdapter(Context c, String [] objects){
          this.c=c;
this.objects=objects;
   }" to  "public MyAdapter(Context c, int position, String [] objects){
            super(c, position, objects);" because I got an error saying there is no default constructor for android.widget.ArrayAdapter

Comment: @Kathy you have to match them with your code. I was only posting an example, but I will help you with that. I will edit the code again matching my code with your variables okay?

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate all of your help and time! :)

Comment: Hmm. I don't see any errors in the code and nothing is red in Android Studio, but whenever I try to run it, it says unfortunately the app has stopped. Is this likely due to my program or something like that?

Comment: You have to connect the phone and there should be caused by in the logcat just show me that exact line

Comment: Sorry it took so long. Here it is: 

08-12 14:13:39.334    6061-6061/com.test.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.test.test, PID: 6061
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.test.test/com.test.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Comment: @Kathy you are putting something before the onCreate () please update your code so that I could help you

Comment: @Kathy This line "new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects)" should be below the setContentView in the activity. So you could actually do this : ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; before the onCreate and then in the onCreate after setContentView you initialize the adapter.. anything more I am ready to help

Answer (score 0):

This would work best with a custom adapter. I would do the following:

1. Keep a master list of possible values.
2. Set the onSelectedItemAdapter to a function that will set the index of the selected item.
3. For the getItem() function, if position=0, use the selected item. If it == 1, use the divider. If 2 or higher, test to see if the position-2 is less than the selected item. If it is, then return the item at position p-2, otherwise return p-1.
4. Set the count of spinner items as one higher than the number in the list (For the divider)

I believe this logic should work, test it with something simple and verify it works before using it in a real example.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand step 3. I feel like there'd be an issue with the rest of the items in the list that aren't selected, since their indexes would be shifted too. Could you further explain? Thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: An adapter can arbitrarily place objects. An array is often used to store these objects, but it isn't the only way. Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html .